# Prioritize network traffic for ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, traffic

How can I prioritize network traffic for my ssh connection to work stable.

I ran some service on Ubuntu, and now I cannot do anything through ssh. Even ping does not respond.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].